# How to search bean class if defined by context:component-scan

Tags: spring, javabeans

All:

I wonder if someone defines bean in Java-based configuration way, like use @component etc in class rather than defined it in xml, and use context:component-scan, when I want to find out the implementation of that bean class, how can I find where it is?

Suppose I am using Eclipse.

Thanks

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + T? I don't use Eclipse, so that's just a guess. Help page: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-keybindings.htm

Comment: @Shawn Bush Thanks, could you give me some detail about this, what I only know is something like context.getBean("beanID"), how can I use this type search to do that?

Comment: What is the class of the bean? If the implementation is in your Eclipse workspace, entering the class of the bean into that command should help you find it.

Comment: @Shawn Bush Thanks, so I have to know the class..

Comment: @Shawn Bush But I wonder when I read annotation like @Resource(name="beanname") how do I know where to find the instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either search for the class name (as default the bean name is the same as the class name with the first letter as lower case) or do a full text search for the bean name in Eclipse (you can limit the search to *.java files to speed up the search).

Comment: Thanks, so for my case, when I come across a @component("beanid") annotation, I have to search all java files for it?

Comment: Yes, if you don't use the default naming convention (which is the class name with lower case first letter), then you have to search for it.